# Custom Attributes As A Product Tab

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes

I am almost there, the theme I have does not use view.html but its a folder called view with parts of the product page. I am trying to make the the custom attributes content show but it refuses to show I tried every method out there can't find a solution.

Here is the code:

```
 <?php 

 $this->_product = Mage::registry('product');
 $tabName = 'custom_product_tab_'.$this->_product['entity_id'];
 $staticBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($tabName);

 $tab2Name = 'custom_product_tab2_'.$this->_product['entity_id'];
 $staticBlock2 = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($tab2Name);  
 $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
 $_product = $this->getProduct();
 $aso = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'as_seen_on', $storeId);
 $video = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'video', $storeId); ?>

 <ul class="meigee-tabs">
 <?php foreach ($this->getTabs() as $_index => $_tab): ?>
 <?php if($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])): ?>
 <li id="product_tabs_<?php echo $_tab['alias'] ?>" class="<?php echo !$_index?' active first':(($_index==count($this->getTabs())-1)?' last':'')?>"><a href="#"><?php echo $_tab['title']?></a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
       <li id="product_aso_tabs" class="last"><div class="tab-left"></div><a href="#">As Seen On</a><div class="tab-right"></div></li>
       <li id="product_video_tabs" class="last"><div class="tab-left"></div><a href="#">Video</a><div class="tab-right"></div></li>
 </ul>
 <?php foreach ($this->getTabs() as $_index => $_tab): ?>
      <?php if($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])): ?>
      <div class="meigee-tabs-content" id="product_tabs_<?php echo $_tab['alias'] ?>_contents">
      <?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias']) ?></div>
      <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>

 <div class="meigee-tabs-content" id="product_aso_tabs_contents"><?php echo $aso; ?></div>
 <div class="meigee-tabs-content" id="product_video_tabs_contents"><?php echo video; ?></div>
```

Here is the javascript included in the file:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     //<![CDATA[
     Varien.Tabs = Class.create();
     Varien.Tabs.prototype = {
          initialize: function(selector) {
       var self=this;
      $$(selector+' a').each(this.initTab.bind(this));
     },

   initTab: function(el) {
       el.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
       if ($(el.parentNode).hasClassName('active')) {
       this.showContent(el);
       }
      el.observe('click', this.showContent.bind(this, el));
    },

    showContent: function(a) {
      var li = $(a.parentNode), ul = $(li.parentNode);
      ul.select('li', 'ol').each(function(el){
       var contents = $(el.id+'_contents');
       if (el==li) {
       el.addClassName('active');
       contents.show();
       } else {
        el.removeClassName('active');
       contents.hide();
     }
      });
     }
   }
   new Varien.Tabs('.meigee-tabs');
  //]]>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

-edit-

First of all i don't see your storeId variable declared, second of all why get the raw value when your productobject is already loaded? use `$this->_product->getVideo();` and `$this->_product->getAsSeenOn();`. If you really want to get the raw value declare your storeId.

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

Also, to make it easier on myself (and code cleaner) I would just put the gettabs in a variable and add my attributes to that.

The js works like this : you have a div with id product_tabs_description and it links to the product_tab_description_contents id, do the same with your attributes and your all done.

Comment: they are marked yes

Comment: I just need the value of custom attributes to show up in the aso/video product tabs

Comment: @Jessica does my edit help you?

Comment: nope no content is showing (please click the video tab - http://goo.gl/4saqA)

Comment: is it possible that it links to the id? because your id should be product_tabs_aso / product_tabs_video then...

Comment: @Jessica see the answer

Comment: how would i be able to test that?

Comment: @Jessica just change the ids of your li and divs to that setup and you're done

Comment: Ok please change your answer to reflect that change. Also I added the javascript for better understanding.